# If I delete the Undertale file in Steamapps, will it delete the soundtrack as well?

Tags: steam, undertale

I did a Neutral Run in Undertale where I decided to kill Flowey. I then reset hoping to do the full Genocide Run when as I approached where you are usually greeted by Flowey, he does not turn up.

I came here and found out you had to delete the Undertale file in Steamapps (because I have Steam) but I realized that I had bought the Undertale soundtrack. So I am wondering if you delete the Undertale file, if it deletes the soundtrack too. I don't want to lose the soundtrack!

[image: Undertale Soundtrack Folder]

Comment: Even if you delete it, you can download it again. Also, if you like the soundtrack so much, why keep it in your Steam folder where it's so hard to reach, when you can just copy it to your library's music folder where it's far easier to reach?

Comment: It is in my library, I just didn't know if it would delete it from there aswell.

Answer (score 6):

First: It sounds odd that you'd have to delete some file(s) for this, but I'll leave this portion for others.

Since you've bought the game on Steam you can (re-)download the game and the soundtrack as often as you want. Everything is associated with your account. If you delete anything, you can open the game's properties and verify the local files to restore anything missing or modified.